# UIAlertController should not be showing

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm making a login app with an alert controller that should not let the user continue if they don't have the correct amount of characters for a password. When I enter the correct amount, the alert controller pops up and does not allow me to continue. Is there something I should not have in my code ?

```
func alertDisplay() {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Five characters or more is required to login", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) {ACTION -> Void in
        // Does nothing
    }
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
        // does nothing also
    }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    alertController.addAction(okAction)

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    let allowedChars = 15
    let passwordCount = passwordField.text?.characters.count

    if passwordCount <= allowedChars {
        // allow user to continue if the amount of characters is less than 15
        alertController.viewDidAppear(false)

    } else {
        // allow user to not be able to continue if they have too many characters

        alertController.viewDidAppear(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Except if you're overriding `viewWillAppear/disappear` , you shouldn't call these methods directly. As calling `dismissViewController` just after calling `presentViewController` : I'm not sure this has a well-defined behavior. You shouldn't fight UIKit (if it looks like a hack, you're probably doing it wrong ;)

Comment: One more thing i think there is no need of cancel button here.

Answer (score 4):

Replace:

```
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

let allowedChars = 15
let passwordCount = passwordField.text?.characters.count

if passwordCount <= allowedChars {
    // allow user to continue if the amount of characters is less than 15
    alertController.viewDidAppear(false)

} else {
    // allow user to not be able to continue if they have too many characters

    alertController.viewDidAppear(true)
}
```

With:

```
let allowedChars = 15
let passwordCount = passwordField.text?.characters.count

if passwordCount > allowedChars {
     self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```